# iOS >> Quart Core 'Corner Radius' Doesn't Affect Navigation Bar in Custom View

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, custom-view, quartz-core

I have a Custom View (subclassing UIView); I'm trying to have its Content View corners rounded.
I'm using QuartzCore relevant properties to do so. At the top of the Content View, there's a Navigation Bar which I cannot seem to embed with these 'Rounded Corners' effects.

[image]

[image]

Here is the code:

```
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    self.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    self.contentView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 8;

    self.navBar.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
}
```

How do I make the Navigation Bar corners round as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can achieve the effect you want by adding

```
self.navBar.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with these lines.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
self.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
self.contentView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
self.contentView.masksToBounds = YES;
```

}